# Process start keeps failing. Starting the exe via code fails

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I am trying to start a WPF application executable via the code below:

```
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                CloseOpen();
            });

void CloseOpen()
{
      string srLocationss = @"" + srLocation + @"\Mycoded.exe";
      Process.Start(srLocationss);
}
```

The executable starts and immediately fails. If I double-click it though, it works. I am really confused.

Here's the error

[image]

Comment: Process.Start returns a Process. Inspect the exit code and go from there.

Comment: Try using `Path.Combine` when combining paths and file names and verify the file exists before running to ensure you have correctly defined the path.

Comment: What does your event log say? Unhandled exceptions are logged in eventlog.

Comment: please post the app startup code , are you creating new dispathers?

Comment: @Saurabh yes i am creating a task and calling this from that task

Comment: Also added error image.

Comment: ok i debugged and it is path problem. so i need to set some options i suppose. it is trying to get invalid path. but if run via double click it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot clearly shows that you did in fact start the program successfully.  But it immediately crashed and displayed the Windows Error Reporting dialog.  You don't have an ExitCode yet because the process hasn't exited yet.  That doesn't happen until you close the dialog.

Clearly the "Debug the program" option is an attractive one.

Many reasons why a process crashes at startup.  By far the most common one is not setting the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.  Poorly written programs often assume that the default working directory is set to the path of the EXE.  And try to load a file with a relative path name instead of a full one (like "mumble.txt" instead of "c:\foo\bar\mumble.txt").  That's a kaboom if the working directory isn't set.  It will not be with your current code.

If this program is your own then improve it by writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.  Display or log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  Now you *know* why it crashed.